# C# How to copy and paste files from a Data Set using a button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a button, that button saves XML files, those XML files consist of files from a certain Data Set, How can i use that same button to copy the files listed, and paste them in a different directory.

Code for my button:

```
private void buttonSaveXML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFile.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
        saveFile.Title = "Save a Xml File";
        saveFile.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\fxo\NewVersion";
        saveFile.ShowDialog();
        if (saveFile.FileName != "")
        {
            FileStream fs = (FileStream)saveFile.OpenFile();
            dsVersions.WriteXml(fs);
        }
```

***Edit***: I need to incorporate a code with this button that will copy and paste ALL the files in a dataGrid and be able to save an xml file while doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [FileSystem.CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127964.aspx) Method to do the job.

Comment: I need to be able to use a button, i edited my question to make it a bit more clear on what i have to do.